# Does Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name) return a new stream on every call?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

The documentation [GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is not clear about multiple calls for the same resource. Does each call guarantee an independent stream instance?

Reason: know if one should worry about concurrent use.

Comment: The documentation of `Assembly` clearly states that the type is thread safe. In my book that includes your scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
internal unsafe Stream GetManifestResourceStream(string name, ref StackCrawlMark stackMark, bool skipSecurityCheck)
{
    // blahblah
    //...
    return new UnmanagedMemoryStream(pointer, (long) length, (long) length, FileAccess.Read, true);
}
```

So, yes.  It would be quite hard to use if it didn't.

Answer (score 3):

Given that streams are stateful, I would be *highly* surprised if two calls received the same `Stream` reference. It would surprise me much less to hear that two streams could both be views onto the same bit of memory, but that should be hidden from the caller.

I think it's reasonable to assume that the streams are independent.

Comment: Thanks. I figured as much but did not see any documentation on it.